# openapi 2 multiple response types

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I know that with openapi 3 I can use oneOf/anyOf but currently we can't upgrade to openapi 3. In one of definitions I need to use many response types which doesn't have common attributes (basically response is interface without any method/attribute and has multiple different implementations). Can I somehow define multiple response types with openapi 2? Is it possible to use for example headers/content-types/... to distinguish between this reponse types and have valid openapi2 definition?

thanks

Comment: Can you add sample responses to your post?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Turns out there can be multiple responses as long as they have different HTTP status code as a "key". `default` keyword is just that, user of API is supposed to expect that if HTTP status is not on the list of responses `default` should be used. (e.g. if somebody uses `switch` to handle responses `default` maps to `default` case in `switch`).

As for single HTTP status code signaling multiple possible types of response, that's not supported explicitly. One ugly workaround would be to create type that contain all the fields, and it would be up to a client to discriminate based on which fields hold values.